# Is it possible to configure log4j to create a new file with every run of the application?

Tags: java, log4j

For example, the first time I run an application (or immediately after I clear out the /logs directory), I want log4j to write the application's logs to a file called log.0. Then, I exit the application and restart it, I want the logs to be written to log.1. And so on.

I would like to keep this in the configuration file, although if I can't, I guess I could always do it in my application, when log4j is set up.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/

**Edit:**I got one more solution! 
But no idea whether it works or not,but you can try 
http://www.mail-archive.com/log4cxx-user@logging.apache.org/msg02132.html

Comment: Yes, I think creating a custom appender is the way to go.

Comment: Please describe *how* to do it. Not link to a will-404-soon random blog.

Answer (score 5):

Solution with log4j2:

```
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/GScraper.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/GScraper_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">
        <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%level\t%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c: %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="32 MB" />
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Note **OnStartupTriggeringPolicy** and **%i** in **filePattern**. This way, Log4j will create new log file with index each time you run the App.

Answer (score 1):

See logback's manual on [uniquely named files (by timestamp)](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed).

Comment: Isn't this answer for another framework, not log4j itself?

At least it does'nt work with log4j for me:
`
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 11 and column 61
log4j:WARN Element type "timestamp" must be declared.
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 18 and column 16
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
´

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I don't think this is possible from with Log4j. Maybe when you shut the application down you could rename the .log file so next time you start up a new log file is created.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm somewhat disappointed. log4j meets all of my needs, and performs well. I just want to be able to group my logs by execution, instead of by date or file size.

Comment: I once wrote an additional adapter for log4j (long story)  the source code is really easy to read and well documented sure it will not take you long to implement this feature :-)