# log4j - one file per run

Tags: java, scala, log4j

I have found a similar question for log4net([log4net one file per run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run)), but i am struggling to convert this to **log4j.properties** file format. The patters just don't get applied:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File = logs/log-%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
...
```

I see what is wrong here, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Post what error you are getting ?

Comment: @rinuthomaz I am not getting an error, I am getting file named "logs/log-%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}.log" (slashes make directories actually)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to configure log4j to create a new file with every run of the application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444520/is-it-possible-to-configure-log4j-to-create-a-new-file-with-every-run-of-the-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you are asking.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/

courtesy :[Is it possible to configure log4j to create a new file with every run of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444520/is-it-possible-to-configure-log4j-to-create-a-new-file-with-every-run-of-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender) with the RollingStyle set to Date. So the config would look something like

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingStyle=Date
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern=yy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss
log4j.appender.file.StaticLogFileName=false
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/log.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

I don't think it is possible to use slashes or colons in the date pattern as these are not characters that can occur in a file name.

Note that this will actually create a new log file every second, which doesn't match what you've asked for in the title of your question. If you really want a new log file for every run then you should set the RollingStyle to Once. But in this case your file name will not contain a date pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Try RollingFileAppender

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: this will roll new file every 5mb, not every application start, won't it?

Comment: roll new file every 5mb